# Why image onload doesn't fire?

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, onload-event

I load some text and image into a div with an xmlhttprequest. Unfortunately the image onload event doesn't works. The code is this:

```
<img src="pic.png" onload="alert('...')"/>
```

I can see the image after the request, but the onload event doesn't fire. Why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be down to caching. The onload event for images is a bit sketchy and doesn't always fire for AJAX requests.

Try adding a query parameter to the request with the current date to stop any caching

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing the javascript within the onload, just call a function, like this:

```
<img src="image.gif" onload="loadImage()" />
```

then in the head of your document, have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadImage()
{
alert("Image is loaded");
}
</script>
```

hope this helps!

Comment: That explanation was straight from the W3C..
Hopefully this issue gets dealt with. Good luck